# Kiddushin by a man who has the din of a חייב מיתה

Tags: halacha, capital-punishment, kiddushin-eirusin

If a man has the din of חייב מיתה and performs קידושין, is his קידושין valid? We know that in the case of a man whose חייב מיתה, if a person were to go and kill that man, the man who killed him would NOT get מיתה בידי בית דין.

Comment: Please [edit] in where we know the law you cite, how - explicitly - you suspect this may impact the laws of kiddushin, and [dejargonification](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon) of all Hebrew terms.

Comment: @David - I see nowhere in Halacho that you can kill a person who is  חייב מיתה.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, note that he didn't say you can.

Comment: Is this question confusing someone who's chayav mitah (by simply committing some aveirah) with someone who had a g'mar din (the beit din rendered a verdict of death). The likelihood of being this being a question is small (because the condemned would have to escape) but the Gemara in perek ben sorer u'moreh does discuss that situation.

Comment: Yes this is after the gemar din

Answer (score 0):

(Disregarding your claim that `a man whose חייב מיתה, if a person were to go and kill that man, the man who killed him would NOT get מיתה בידי בית דין.` which I'm sure is not true.)

The Mishna in Arochin (1:3) says:

> א,ג  הגוסס, והיוצא ליהרג--לא נידר, ולא נערך; רבי חנניה בן עקביה אומר, נערך, מפני שדמיו קצובין, אבל אינו נידר, מפני שאין דמיו קצובין.  רבי יוסי אומר, נודר ומעריך ומקדיש; ואם הזיק, חייב בתשלומין.

See that Bartenura there that all agree that he can be ומקדיש- as in "make it Holy".

The argument is whether he pays for items he damages.

There's no reason to assume he cannot marry somebody; the Rambam would have codified it somewhere...